# How to safely and smoothly update packages on server?(by apt)

Tags: apt, packages

On my own computer, I have been used to run `apt-get upgrade` directly for years.

But few days ago I have a chance to admin a ubuntu server. I guess my old habit is bad.

Should/how I update security updates only to minimize dependence issus?

And how can I confirm the source is trustworthy(by SHA or other hash), keep the middleman attack away?

Comment: Ubuntu repositories are GnuPG-signed; apt-get will verify the signature each time you do an 'update'.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apt-get` is fine on an Ubuntu system. If you only want to include security related updates, make sure that you don't have the `lucid-updates` distro in your source list (i.e. only have `lucid` and `lucid-security`). All the package tools will verify GPG signatures and SHA hashes by default, and will explicitly prompt you to continue if they are unable to do so.